# How to get Values of another table using one table using LINQ

Tags: sql, entity-framework, linq, lambda

I've Three tables `Master`,`Users`,`Category` like below

```
  Master Table :                                Users Table :     Category Table :
+---+------------+-----------+------------+     +----+------+    +----+-------+
|ID | CategoryID | CreatedBy | UpdatedBy  |     | ID | Name |    | ID | Name  |
+---+------------+-----------+------------+     +----+------+    +----+-------+
| 1 |    1       |    1      |     1      |     | 1  | Ravi |    |  1 | Fruit |
| 2 |    2       |    2      |     1      |     | 2  | Balu |    |  2 | Toys  |
| 3 |    2       |    2      |     2      |     +----+------+    +----+-------+
+---+------------+-----------+------------+
```

In **Master** table `CretedBy` and `UpdatedBy` id's are referenced to **Users** table. I wrote the LINQ to get the data from **Users** and **Category** tables like below :

```
var result = (from p in db.Master join q in db.Category on p.CategoryID equals q.ID join r in db.Users on p.CreatedBy equals r.ID select new {p,q,r}).ToList();
```

From Here i can able to get the `CreatedBy` value from **Users** table. But, also how to get the value of `UpdatedBy` from **Users** table using LINQ?

Can you please help me?

Thanks in Advance !!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to join one more time just like you would write an SQL Query

```
    var result = (
    from p in db.Master 
    join q in db.Category on p.CategoryID equals q.ID 
    join u1 in db.Users on p.CreatedBy equals u1.ID 
    join u2 in db.Users on p.UpdatedBy equals u2.ID 
    select new {
        p, 
        q, 
        u1,
        u2,
    }).ToList();
```